# How to define a run-time exception in c++?

Tags: c++

What's the correct way to define a user-defined run-time exception in c++?

I want to define a simple exception and be able to store a string message value in it?

I can't find any examples on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class my_exception : public std::exception
{
public:
 my_exception(const std::string& msg) : msg_(msg) {}
 const char* what(); // override what to return msg_;
private:
    std::string msg_;
};

//some other code..

throw my_exception("Error");
```

This is how you'd create a new run-time exception.  It's just a `class`

Comment: What not `what()` override? (It is probably simpler to just use `std::runtime_error` either directly or as a base class.)

Answer (score 4):

You can find some predefined exception types in the header `<stdexcept>`.

Either use one of those or derive your class from it. It has all the machinery already implemented.

Comment: +1 but there are total 7 per-defined exception in stdexcept,and even msdn gives the non-helping examples of those exception like : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k58422wy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx , rather then telling when they occur, explaining them good. Might be you can share some link which explains them deeply or you explain them in short? :)

Comment: No, I don't think there is any explanations to the hierarchies. The standards committee just once felt like they wanted to have some examples of exception types. If you have a runtime error, just derive it from `std::runtime_error` and you're done.